# How to get touch position in percentage in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am implementing drawing for the android device.   The problem is when i am drawing into different resolution device and view same drawing in different  then its position is not same.
  Now i thinking to get  touch position in % so i can redraw drawing into other devices.

for touch position I am using:

```
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       float x = event.getX();
       float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
}
return true;
}
```

I am getting co-ordinates (200,300), Is there any way to get co-ordinates in percentage 10%,20%,
 or we have to calculate it pro-grammatically.

Comment: Not a good idea to do that though, because you will have to deal with data being lost due to mathematic calculation. Not good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code to get Device's height and width and save them to variable, 
like this

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

After getting your X and Y use below mentioned function to get percentage

```
int percentageX= (int)((x*100)/width)
int percentageY= (int)((y*100)/height)
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert back to its original values? How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The touch events always return the x,y coordinates of the pixels.  If you want a percentage, you will have to do it programmatically.  You can do it pretty simply though.  You just need to know the size of your screen, then divide accordingly to get the percent.